# How to use the OGR/GDAL configure options in QGIS Python environment

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, ogr, gml

I'm looking for a solution how to use the OGR/GDAL configure options (--config) in the QGIS Python environment. http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions

Setting special configure options is necessary to load some data correctly (OGR Driver).

```
QgsVectorLayer(filename, title, "ogr")
```

Answer (score 4):

One usually sets options in C with [CPLSetConfigOption](http://www.gdal.org/cpl__conv_8h.html#aa0cd1a68fe4f2fc7874cd2da605c36ce). In python it would be `gdal.SetConfigOption(option, value)`, e.g., `gdal.SetConfigOption('PG_USE_COPY', 'YES')`

Answer (score 0):

In the C and C++ API you can use

```
CPLSetConfigOption("GDAL_DATA", "your folder path with gdal-data");
```

In Qt I use

```
CPLSetConfigOption("GDAL_DATA", QDir( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath().append("/gdal-data")).absolutePath().toLocal8Bit() );
```

As my gdal-data folder is relative to the executable path.